# Parameter not passed through the constructor

Tags: java, class, constructor, parameter-passing

```
abstract class shape{
    public double volume;
    public double surface;
}

class cube extends shape{

    public static double side;
    public static double newSide;

    cube(double newSide){
        side = newSide;
        }

    public double volume(){
        return side;
    }

    public double surface(){
        return newSide;
    }
}



public class shapes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        cube a = new cube(5);
        System.out.println (a.volume);
        System.out.println (a.surface);
    }
```

}

This produces:

0.0
0.0

The parameter I am passing through the constructor does not seem to be processed properly by the cube class.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Not a java expert but I think you are printing the member variable `volume` instead of calling the function `volume()`. (java allows variables and methods to have the same name, and selects one based on whether you use `()` or not)

Answer (score 1):

So my guess is you haven’t figured out what objects are. If you look at the JDK code you will see examples of classes that define objects  java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.StringBuilder are classes you can look at to get some idea of what objects are. Once you see how some of these classes work you can get the idea for the motivation behind the rest of this.

There are objects and there are classes. We use classes as templates to create objects. Each object has its own state. For example you  can have many different strings in your program. Each string is an object with its own state, using its own instance variables. But static variables don’t belong to objects, they belong to the class.

“Instance” means one occurrence of an object. We instantiate objects using a constructor.

Your methods like

```
 public double volume(){
```

are called accessors, or getters, because they’re used to access the state of the object.

Having an instance method accessor access a static variable is confusing. Static members have a different scope than instance members and combining them here is confusing. It’s hard to tell what is intended but you shouldn’t be using static variables to describe state that should be specific to an instance.

Your static variables are public and have the same name as the accessor. If you call the member without parens you are calling the variable directly. If you use parens you will call the accessor. .

In the event you do need static variables, you don’t initialize  them in a constructor. Constructors are for initializing an instance of the class, where static variables don’t belong to one instance but to the class. Use constructors to set instance variables, not static ones.